# bottomrule not working in a self-made environment

Tags: vertical-alignment, environments, rules

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [bottomrule not working in a self-made environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6910/bottomrule-not-working-in-a-self-made-environment)

I have this environment for consistent tables in my latex documents:

```
\newenvironment{defaultTable}[2] {
    \@float{table}[h]
    \noindent
    \tabularx{\textwidth}{#1}
    \specialrule{0.5pt}{10pt}{0pt}
    \rowcolor[gray]{.9}
    \gdef\mycaption{#2}
} {
    \bottomrule
    \endtabularx
    \emph{\caption{\mycaption}}
    \end@float
}
```

Unfortunately, the line with \bottomrule leads to this error, which i don't understand:

> ! Misplaced \noalign. \bottomrule
>   ->\noalign 
>                          {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \@aboverulesep =\aboverulesep
>   \global... l.27 \end{defaultTable}

When I use it inside the environment it works though

```
\begin{defaultTable}{X X}{Blablah Table}
(..)
\bottomrule
\end{defaultTable}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I assume the case where it works has `{defaultTable}` defined not to have `\bottomrule`, but otherwise be the same.

Comment: It would have been helpful to have posted a complete working example, including the packages you were assuming to have this code work.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is caused by the `\noalign` in the definition of `\bottomrule`.  You can define a new version of `\bottomrule` for use within the environment and then things should work. (You shouldn't redefine `\bottomrule` in case you use it outside of the environment.)  The definition is taken from the `booktabs` source.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,colortbl}
\makeatletter
\def\envbottomrule{{\ifnum0=`}\fi
  \@aboverulesep=\aboverulesep
  \global\@belowrulesep=\belowbottomsep
  \global\@thisruleclass=\@ne
  \@ifnextchar[{\@BTrule}{\@BTrule[\heavyrulewidth]}}
\newenvironment{defaultTable}[2] {
    \@float{table}[h]
    \noindent
    \tabularx{\textwidth}{#1}
    \specialrule{0.5pt}{10pt}{0pt}
    \rowcolor[gray]{.9}
    \gdef\mycaption{#2}
} {%
    \envbottomrule
    \endtabularx
    \emph{\caption{\mycaption}}
    \end@float
}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{defaultTable}{XX}{A caption}%
foo & bar\\
foo & bar
\end{defaultTable}

\end{document}
```