# How to include tabularx/y in a new environment?

Tags: tables, environments, tabularx

I am looking for a way to define a customizable environment for tables in my latex documents. This means:

- caption and label
- width of table
- customized column format (tabular preamble)

While this seems to be easy for figures, I am desparately looking for a solution for tables. Here is my minimal code example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=14pt,DIV=calc]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tabularx,tabulary}

\newenvironment{tabfig}[4]
{\begin{table}
 \captionabove{#2}\label{tab:#1}
 \begin{tabularx}{#3}{#4}}
{\end{tabularx}\end{table}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabfig}{MyLabel}{MyCaption}{0.8\textwidth}{l >{\centering}X >{\centering}X}
    A & B & C \tabularnewline
    x & y & z \tabularnewline
  \end{tabfig}
\end{document}
```

I have done thorough research for several days by now and also tried `\bgroup`, `\begingroup`, `\begintabularx`, the `cprotect` package and various other things. Though, I could not come up with something useful in this general case. Folks, I cannot believe I am the first to write a customizable table environment. Is there anybody to light the light?

Comment: The problem here is that tabularx is not actually an environment, it only looks like that. It is a command which reads the whole command in one go, which doesn't work if you wrap it in another environment. (But the folk at tex.stackexchange certainly have some solution.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=14pt,DIV=calc]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tabularx,tabulary}

\newenvironment{tabfig}[4]{%
     \table\centering%
     \captionabove{#2}\label{tab:#1}%
     \tabularx{#3}{#4}%
}{%
     \endtabularx%
     \endtable%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
 \captionabove{MyCaption}\label{tab:MyLabel}
 \begin{tabularx}{0.8\textwidth}{l >{\centering}X >{\centering}X}
    A & B & C \tabularnewline
    x & y & z \tabularnewline
\end{tabularx}\end{table}

  \begin{tabfig}{MyLabel}{MyCaption}{0.8\textwidth}{l >{\centering}X >{\centering}X}
    A & B & C \tabularnewline
    x & y & z \tabularnewline
  \end{tabfig}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice way to environment-ize the "macro".

Comment: @Werner: it's in the documentation for  **tabularx**.

Comment: @Werner Nice hint, `\table` helped a lot! But I cannot add anything in the end part of the environment definition (e.g. `\bottomrule` from `booktabs`). Second, is there a way to center the whole table horizontally on the page? `\begin{center}` does not work anymore... @egreg `\endtabularx` is in the documentation (hidden in the macro part), `\table` is not.

Comment: @Rene: Updated to [center horizontally](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures). See this link [about \bottomrule in a self made environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6910/bottomrule-not-working-in-a-self-made-environment)

Comment: @Peter: You solved a question that cost me a lot of time, indeed! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Since the solution is not completely trivial, I would like to summarize the answers to the question in a complete code example to use in your documents:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=14pt,DIV=calc]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tabularx,tabulary,booktabs,environ}

\newlength{\tabmargin}% necessary if you want the caption to be aligned with the table
\newlength{\tabwidth}%

\NewEnviron{tabfigx}[4]{%
 \setlength{\tabwidth}{#3}\setlength{\tabmargin}{\linewidth}%
 \addtolength{\tabmargin}{-\the\tabwidth}\setcapmargin{0.5\tabmargin}%
 \table[!htb]%
 \captionabove{#2}\label{tab:#1}%
 \centering%
 \tabularx{#3}{#4}%
 \toprule%
 \BODY%
 \bottomrule% or what else you would like to do after the table has been done...
}[\endtabularx\endtable]%

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabfigx}{MyLabel}{MyCaption}{0.8\textwidth}{l >{\centering}X >{\centering}X}
    A & B & C \tabularnewline
    x & y & z \tabularnewline
  \end{tabfigx}
\end{document}
```

If you want to use the `tabulary` package, just define a similar macro `tabfigy` and change the lines containing `\tabularx` and `\endtabularx` accordingly.
An alternative way is to use the [floatrow](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/floatrow) package. Personally, I will stay with KOMA script plus some extending macros.