# Shortcut macro for tabularx environment

Tags: macros, errors, tabularx

I'm trying to define a shortcut using `\newcommand` for setting up a table using the `tabularx` environment. The command seems to work fine when beginning the table:

```
\newcommand{\bt}{\begin{tabularx}}
```

But doesn't work when ending the table:

```
\newcommand{\et}{\end{tabularx}}
```

The error message that I receive is:

```
! Missing } inserted.

<inserted text> 

                }

l.33 \end{tabularx}
```

Comment: Hi Richard, welcome to TeX.sx! I've formatted the code in your question. You can also do that yourself by selecting the code segments and clicking the `{}` button. Also, it's generally a good idea to include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), i.e. the smallest complete, compilable document that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: The `tabularx` environment only looks like an environment, but it's actually a command.  See [How to include tabularx/y in a new environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25776/2693).

Answer (score 5):

An environment `\begin{tabularx}` expands to `\begingroup\tabularx` and
`\end{tabularx}` expands to `\endtabularx\endgroup`.

With `\let\a\b` you can 'copy' the definition of macro `\b` to `\a`.
That's how you create the short name:

```
\let\bt\tabularx
\let\et\endtabularx
```

Note: This does not copy the group.

Usage:

```
\bt{5cm}{lX}
 foo & bar
\et
```

Comment: Definition: Check, Usage: Check, Explanation: ???