# How to align manually-typed list of abbreviation table (2 columns)

Tags: acronyms, thesis, front-matter

I try to prepare my "list of abbreviation" for my thesis on a separate frontmatter page (namely "listofabbreviations"), so it will be easy to review and edit. It will have two columns and looks something like this:

```
TYT     Take your Time
TTYL    Talk to you Later
```

I want to learn how to align these two columns properly and efficiently for dozens of rows in total. I know people recommend to use nomencl and glossaries packages, etc. But they don't seem to be easily adapted into the template I am using (due to my inexperience)...So, right now I just created the below in my permeable, and try to manually type my list.

```
\newcommand{\listofabbreviations}{
    \chapter*{List of Abbreviations}
    \noindent   
    \input{frontmatter/listofabbreviations}
    \vspace*{\fill} \newpage
}
```

I hope people can help me out. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Coud you post a minimal, yet compilable,  example?

Comment: this answer addresses a very similar situation:  [Aligning items inside a list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98622/579).  other answers to the question suggest various tabular environments, but i think that `tabbing` is more flexible for most lists of this sort.

Comment: Out of interest, what template is it? There is absolutely no Need to follow any of the templates restrictions. The way you wanted to prepare the list, is such a restriction.

Comment: It's just a PhD thesis template I downloaded from Overleaf, and I believe it's from Harvard. I'm new to Latex, so I feel the template just helps me to build up my work.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility would be a `tabular` environment (or if the list is more than one page long, a `longtable` environment).

Or, alternatively, a kind of customized `description` environment. See both possibilities in the document below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcommand{\abbrevlabel}[1]{#1\hfil}
\newenvironment{listabbrev}
    {\begin{list}{}{\let\makelabel\abbrevlabel
          \setlength{\labelwidth}{2cm}%
          \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth+\labelsep}}}
    {\end{list}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{longtable}[l]{lp{10cm}}
TYT   &  Take your Time \\
TTYL  &  Talk to you Later \\
\end{longtable}

\begin{listabbrev}
\item[TYT]     Take your Time
\item[TTYL]    Talk to you Later
 \end{listabbrev}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think my class is {book}, is that still okay to use those packages in your comment?

Comment: You can do an `\input` of a file. Or do you mean that the input file is just the text like you presented without any formatting? I assumed, because you did use `\input{frontmatter/listofabbreviations}`, that that file would have it properly formatted, for example with the `longtable`.

Comment: I see your point now. Longtable works well for my purpose. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

just realize another way to do the trick:

```
\begin{itemize}[label={}]
    \item{\makebox[2cm]{$TYT$\hfill} Take your Time}
    \item{\makebox[2cm]{$TTYL$\hfill}  Talk to you Later}
    \item{\makebox[2cm]{$TYVM$\hfill} Thank You Very Much}
\end{itemize}
```

to use the above, need to first add \usepackage{enumitem} to .cls to avoid the bullets.[image]

Comment: I think you shouldn't put the keywords in `$...$`. That makes the spacing wrong. it interprets `TYT` as a multiplication of three variables: T, Y and T. If you want italic then use `\textit{TYT}` or `\emph{TYT}`. And with my solution you can build that in the definition, so that you don't have to repeat it for every keyword. Like `\newcommand{\abbrevlabel}[1]{\textit{#1}\hfil}` And with my solution you don't have to repeat the `\makebox[2cm]`. In this way it will be easier if you want to change the layout later. "DRY" = Don't Repeat Yourself.

Comment: sounds good. Let me play with your solution a bit. thanks!