# Using tabularx in a custom environment - "misplaced \noalign"

Tags: tables, environments, tabularx

## Question

Currently, I'm trying to shorten the creation of small `tabularx`-tables with pre-defined headers, but somehow, trying to use the `tabularx`-environment, even though I used the `\tabularx` and `\endtabularx` commands, inside my own yields to errors I fail to understand.

My current approach:

```
\newenvironment{predtable}[1]%
  {%
    \par\nolinenumbers%
    \captionof{table}{#1}%
    \tabularx{\textwidth}{|l| c c c |}%
        \hline%
         & Heading & Heading & Heading \\%
        \hline%
  }%
  {%
        \hline%
    \endtabularx%
    \linenumbers%
  }
```

This was supposed to ease table creation such that writing

```
\begin{predtable}
    item1 & item2 & item3 & item4\\
\end{predtable}
```

would be enough.

However, while I don't get errors when defining the environment, using it gets me the error `Misplaced \noalign \end{predtable}`.

## Working example

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, bottom=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[pagewise, modulo]{lineno}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newenvironment{predtable}[1]%
{%
 \par\nolinenumbers%
 \captionof{table}{#1}%
 \tabularx{\textwidth}{|l| C C C |}%
     \hline%
       & Heading 1 & Heading 1 & Heading 1 \tabularnewline%
     \hline%
}%
{%
     \hline%
 \endtabularx%
 \linenumbers%
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{predtable}{Caption goes here!}
        Label & Contents & go & here!\tabularnewline
    \end{predtable}
\end{document}
```

`line 26: Misplaced \noalign \end{predtable}`

Comment: some related posts [How to include tabularx/y in a new environment?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25776) and [tabularx inside a \newenvironment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42325)

Comment: Thank you. I stumbled over both posts while searching for answers, but did not found something exactly resembling mine. I now updated the question with the corrected code (using `\tabularx` instead of the environment) and added the error I'm getting.

Comment: Can you add a complete example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`? This way we wouldn't need to guess at what package you're using.

Comment: I've updated the OP with a minimal code example. It does still produce the error I get in my document, although the formatting seems to be correct this time. But I'm pretty sure that the messed-up formatting in my document is related to that error, as normal `tabularx`-tables work fine.

Comment: You probably missed `\\` before `\hline`.
Try input `\\` .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Placing any alignment material (including `\hline`) in the end clause here doesn't work, I think because of the way `tabularx` scans ahead for the table material.

Fortunately there is a much easier approach using the [`environ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/environ) package.  First a simple basic example:

[image: Simple example]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,environ}

\NewEnviron{simplepredtable}{%
 \begin{tabularx}{0.9\textwidth}{|l| XXX |}
     \hline
       & Heading 1 & Heading 1 & Heading 1 \tabularnewline
     \hline
     \BODY
     \hline
   \end{tabularx}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{simplepredtable}
  Label & Contents & go & here!\tabularnewline
\end{simplepredtable}

\end{document}
```

The `environ` package collects the text of the new environment up in a command `\BODY` which can then be inserted in to some other code.  This enables us to write a block that looks like a usual `\begin{xtabular}...\end{xtabular}`.  I have reduced the width of the table, just to avoid overfull boxes.

For your case, very much the same works, and we can pass your caption argument too:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[top=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, bottom=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx,environ}

\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=sc]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage[pagewise,modulo]{lineno}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\NewEnviron{predtable}[1]{%
 \par\nolinenumbers%
 \captionof{table}{#1}%
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l| C C C |}
   \hline
   & Heading 1 & Heading 1 & Heading 1 \tabularnewline
   \hline
   \BODY
   \hline
 \end{tabularx}
 \vspace{\partopsep}
 \par\linenumbers%
}

\usepackage{lipsum} %For demonstration text

\begin{document}
\linenumbers

\lipsum[1]

\begin{predtable}{Caption goes here!}
  Label & Contents & go & here!\tabularnewline
\end{predtable}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

The `lipsum` package has been added so we get some text to demonstrate the line numbering, notice the extra `\par` command.  I have also put some vertical space after the table so it doesn't run up against the followin text.  However, I would seriously consider wrapping it in say a `center` environment instead, which would itself provide some vertical spacing.

Comment: This approach is really helpful also for those package derived from `tabularx`, like -for example- `xltabular`!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same thing and found that the solution was quite simple, i.e. I was missing adding a newline at the end of the table. Try adding newline or \\ at the end of the content of table.