# Missing } inserted when using newenvironment

Tags: macros

```
\begin{block}{Command} \newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{2}{@{}l}@{}R}
        1 & 2 & 3
    \end{tabularx}
\end{block}
```

Since this is a bit cumbersome, I want to use `\newenvironment` to make things easier.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\newenvironment{Command}[1]
{\begin{block}{Command}%
    \newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}%
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{#1}{@{}l}@{}R}%
}{  \end{tabularx}%
\end{block}}

\begin{document}

% THIS IS CORRECT
% \begin{block}{Command} \newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
%     \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{2}{@{}l}@{}R}
%         1 & 2 & 3
%     \end{tabularx}
% \end{block}

% THIS IS INCORRECT
\begin{Command}{2}
        1 & 2 & 3
\end{Command}

\end{document}
```

This is what I've tried, but it doesn't work, and the error message is

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text>
}
l.nn        \end{tabularx}
```

**EDITED**

According to the thread @TeXnician mentioned, I tried

```
\newenvironment{Command}[1]
{   \newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}%
    \tabularx{\textwidth}{#1}%
}{  \endtabularx}
```

and it does work. However, if `\begin{block}\end{block}` are added, the warning pops up:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\endbeamercolorbox ->\ifdim \beamer@colbox@sep 
                                               =0pt\else \vskip \beamer@colb...
l.nn ^^I\end{block}
```

Comment: What packages?  What packages!  This is why a complete MWE and not just code snippets are vital.

Comment: You can't hide tabularx like this in an environment. See page 4 of the documentation.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I use package beamer.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks. The solution is in page 4. Use `\tabularx{XX}` and `\endtabularx` instead of `\begin{tabularx}{XX}` and `\end{tabularx}`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include tabularx/y in a new environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25776/how-to-include-tabularx-y-in-a-new-environment)

Comment: @TeXnician The solution still cannot work with beamer blocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try with the environ package:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{warsaw}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{environ}


\NewEnviron{Command}[1]
{\begin{block}{command} %
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{#1}{@{}l}@{}R}%
    \BODY
    \end{tabularx}
 \end{block}
}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}

\begin{Command}{2}
     1 & 2 & 3 \\
     abc & abc & abc
\end{Command}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Update 3/2019:

It also works with the new xparse version and its new `b`-type argument:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{warsaw}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{Command}{m b}
{\begin{block}{command} %
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{#1}{@{}l}@{}R}%
    #2
    \end{tabularx}
 \end{block}
}


\begin{document}


\begin{frame}

\begin{Command}{2}
     1 & 2 & 3 \\
     abc & abc & abc
\end{Command}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```